# find_if always giving first element and not going in isOdd function

Tags: c++, stl

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <time.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

bool isOdd(int n)
{ 
    cout << "HELLO";  
    bool val  = ((n%2) == 1); 
    cout << val << endl;
    return val;
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    vector<int> myVec;
    myVec.reserve(20);

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {   
        myVec[i] = rand() % 100;
        cout << myVec[i] << " ";
    }   

    vector<int>::iterator q = std::find_if(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), isOdd);

    cout << setw(3) << "first odd = " << *q << endl;

}
```

The above program always outputs the first number of the vector and is not going in the isOdd function. I am usinf MacOSX and compiling the program using `g++ odd.cpp`

Please help

Comment: Oh no, `myVec` is empty! You probably meant to use `resize` instead of `reserve`.

Comment: Or `myVec.emplace_back(rand() % 100);`.

Comment: The vector is not empty, I am printing the elements of the vector

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla No, you're *invoking Undefined Behaviour.* `reserve` does not affect vector size, and using `[]` beyoned vector size is UB.

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla You have undefined behavior. Your vector is in fact empty and you assigning data to non-existing elements. Appearing to work up to a point is a typical outcome of undefined behavior. Observing your application having the behavior you expect up to a point is not enough to say conclusively that the program is correct up to that point.

Comment: @Rakete1111 That should be an answer.

Comment: operator[] does not require that the element exists in the vector.  When you go out of range, you read invalid memory *as if* it was an object, but it is not.  end() actually knows where the end of the vector is, and find_if is done before it begins because it starts at the end.

Comment: works for me: https://wandbox.org/permlink/SnYDFxJVhVnX39JD (I've just replaced reserve with resize).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem is in these lines:

```
 vector<int> myVec;
 myVec.reserve(20);
```

`std::vector::reserve()` reserves memory for 20 elements, but does not change vector size. Accessing those elements through `std::vector::operator[]` seems to "work" to you but leads to UB as you access elements out of range. You can check that replacing it with `std::vector::at()` which does validate index.

Simply replace those 2 lines by:

```
vector<int> myVec( 20 );
```

that will create vector with 20 elements equal to 0.

Note: your loop should not use magic number and should be written as:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < myVec.size(); i++)
```

if you write it properly you would notice the issue immediately.

Note2: there is no guarantee that you will get any odd number so you have to validate iterator, returned by `std::find_if` before you dereference it.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't crash since `reserve` has allocated needed memory and `operator[]` do not check index range.

In your code `std::find_if` returns always `myVec.end()`, since when you've used only `reserved` size of the vector is always zero and `myVec.begin() == myVec.end()`.

You are referencing a iterator which is `end()` so it is undefined behavior, but most STL libraries will pint to the beginning of reserved memory, where is you "first" value located.

So fix it [by changing](https://wandbox.org/permlink/SnYDFxJVhVnX39JD) `reserve` with `resize` or like other answer point out.

To fully fix your code it should look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <time.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

bool isOdd(int n)
{ 
    cout << "HELLO";  
    bool val  = ((n%2) == 1); 
    cout << val << endl;
    return val;
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    vector<int> myVec(20);

    for(int i = 0; i < myVec.size(); i++)
    {   
        myVec[i] = rand() % 100;
        cout << myVec[i] << " ";
    }   

    vector<int>::iterator q = std::find_if(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), isOdd);

    if (q != myVec.end()) {
        cout << setw(3) << "first odd = " << *q << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Odd values not found!!!\n";
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `push_back`.

```
 vector<int> myVec;

            for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {   
                myVec.push_back(rand() % 100);
                cout << myVec[i] << " ";
            }
```

Since`Push_back` increases the size of vector by one each time , the final size is 20.